# Operator precedence with one AND and one OR

Tags: javascript, operators

Let us have 3 variables of type boolean - `a, b, c`. You can choose the values of these values to be whatever you like (*TRUE* or *FALSE*).

Is it possible to create an expression using the three values only once and using only *&& (AND)* operator, *|| (OR)* operator and brackets to make it give us a different result if the brackets were removed.

For example:

```
var a = false;
var b = false;
var c = false;
var d = true;
console.log(  a || b && c || d  );
console.log(  (a || b) && (c || d)  );
```

will give us different results because of the brackets.

Is it possible to find an expression using **only three** variables? I'm using JavaScript but the question is also valid for C, Java, etc...

Comment: Uh... of course it's possible. If it were not possible you would never need to use brackets in any boolean expression involving three values.

Comment: @Jon - any sample will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible. For example:

```
var a = true;
var b = false;
var c = false;

console.log(a || b && c);
console.log((a || b) && c);
```